# How to read a texfile using BufferedReader

Tags: java, android

I have a text file inside asset folder.I am trying to read it using Buffered reader as chars But I am stuck .Can you please help.

```
    InputStream in=assetManager.open("readme.txt");
        BufferedReader bf=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        int x;
        String s="";

        while((s=bf.readLine())!=null){
            Character.to



        }
```

Comment: It looks like incomplete code for me. Can you post the entire code?. BTW where is the exception trace.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what your problem is? Also, do you really NEED to use BufferedReader? I find Scanner to be easier to use.

Comment: Side note: `String s="";` initialization not needed here.

Comment: please post complete code as this does code does not make sense. although because your question kind of makes sense so not down-voting or flagging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
char[] ch = s.toCharArray();
```

if you want to get the string as character array.

Comment: I don't understand why this is the accepted answer. It is not answering what the question seemed to be... oO Well if it helped the OP, then fine ^^

Answer (score 0):

**Try like below**

```
String txt= null;
        try {
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("readme.txt");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            txt= new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader bf = null;
        try {
            InputStreamReader in= new InputStreamReader(assetManager.open("readme.txt");
            bf=new BufferedReader(in);
            String s="";
            s = bf.readLine();
            while (s != null) {
                s = bf.readLine(); 
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
        } 
        finally {
            if (bf != null) {
                bf.close();
            }
        }
```

This is the complete code, written from the point where @user3468916 left.